# How to extract Windows XP Extended File Information?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, console-application

does someone know a tool which extracts the Extended File Information under WinXP into a file (csv,xml)?

Answer (score 0):

Give SysInternals a try. SysInternals was bought by Microsoft a couple of years ago, so you'll have to do a little digging around to get the info that you need, but it will be well worth it. I've been using their software for nearly a decade now. Click [here](http://www.sysinternals.com) for SysInternals